# Fotorama zoom magento2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, fotorama

How to change the size of Fotorama zoom on magento2.1 to 700px?
I tried it on gallery.phtml but nothing changed.

Comment: do you want to change full screen zoom ?

Comment: Yes, i want to show zoom in with custom CSS pixel. width:600px height:700px

Comment: Have you tried with `view.xml` for var `fullscreenzoom` ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't change anything

Comment: any update for this qiestion?